# Exclude unit test categories in MonoDevelop 3.0

Tags: macos, mono, nunit, monodevelop

I have a .NET project with 2000 unit tests written in NUnit, that I would like to migrate to Mono.

The project is recompiled using Mono 3.0.2/MonoDevelop 3.0.5 on Mac OS X.
I am able to run all unit tests using the integrated test runner of MonoDevelop.

However, I have a lot of tests marked "LongRunning" using `TestCaseAttribute`:

```
[TestCase(1, Category="LongRunning")]
```

but I couldn't exclude them using Unit Test Options (from menu View -> Pads -> Unit Tests -> ...).

[image]

Including/excluding categories options are there but trying them has no effect.

*How do I exclude LongRunning unit tests using MonoDevelop test runner?*

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about this option. But it doesn't work here either (on linux). I suspect a bug. If I add that filter then close and reopen the solution, the value I entered is forgotten.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks for your info. If I couldn't find a solution (or workaround) soon, I probably have to submit a bug report to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the two problems are separate. This patch should fix your problem:

```
diff --git a/main/src/addins/NUnit/Services/NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.cs b/main/src/addins/NUnit/Services/NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.cs
index 385e50f..b2addd6 100644
--- a/main/src/addins/NUnit/Services/NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.cs
+++ b/main/src/addins/NUnit/Services/NUnitAssemblyTestSuite.cs
@@ -357,19 +357,19 @@ namespace MonoDevelop.NUnit
                        ITestFilter filter = null;
                        if (test != null) {
                                if (test is UnitTestGroup) {
-                                       filter = new TestNameFilter (CollectTests ((UnitTestGroup)test));
+                                       NUnitCategoryOptions categoryOptions = (NUnitCategoryOptions) test.GetOptions (typeof(NUnitCategoryOptions));
+                                       if (categoryOptions != null && categoryOptions.EnableFilter && categoryOptions.Categories.Count > 0) {
+                                               string[] cats = new string [categoryOptions.Categories.Count];
+                                               categoryOptions.Categories.CopyTo (cats, 0);
+                                               filter = new CategoryFilter (cats);
+                                               if (categoryOptions.Exclude)
+                                                       filter = new NotFilter (filter);
+                                       } else {
+                                               filter = new TestNameFilter (CollectTests ((UnitTestGroup)test));
+                                       }
                                } else {
                                        filter = new TestNameFilter (test.TestId);
                                }
-                       } else {
-                               NUnitCategoryOptions categoryOptions = (NUnitCategoryOptions) test.GetOptions (typeof(NUnitCategoryOptions));
-                               if (categoryOptions.EnableFilter && categoryOptions.Categories.Count > 0) {
-                                       string[] cats = new string [categoryOptions.Categories.Count];
-                                       categoryOptions.Categories.CopyTo (cats, 0);
-                                       filter = new CategoryFilter (cats);
-                                       if (categoryOptions.Exclude)
-                                               filter = new NotFilter (filter);
-                               }
                        }

                        RunData rd = new RunData ();
```

I also have a patch for the other problem (settings not being written) but even though it doesn't touch serialization code, MD can not read back the properties it saves. I am looking into that.

Comment: +1 for willing to help. Any idea how I should apply the fix? I use binary distribution of MonoDevelop. Maybe recompile NUNit add-in from source and re-add it to MonoDevelop? Once you solve the problem with written settings, please submit a pull request to MonoDevelop on Github. I think many others will benefit from your help.

Comment: I have [uploaded a binary version](http://www.sendspace.com/file/fhi5u9), no guarantees that it's compatible with your MD.

Comment: No, it isn't. When I start MonoDevelop, there is an error message complaining that `MonoDevelop.NUnit.dll` has the wrong public key.

Comment: The bug is reopened https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9680 . It seems not to be fixed soon, sigh.

Comment: Yeah I must have messed something up with the patch, although I did check single tests were working here. Going to look at it again.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm looking forward to a fix.